# Content Sources Settings Revert

Tags: content, settings, crawl

Getting a strange glitch when editing the settings on my content sources.
I'm trying to experiment a bit within the "Crawl Settings" category.  Specifically, I'm looking at the "Limit Page Depth" and "Limit Server Hops".

I set up these custom crawl settings but the radio button keeps reverting back to "Only crawl within the server of each start address".
Sometimes I can bypass this glitch by making a new content source.  If I edit it later, it reverts again.

The crawl isn't running when I make these edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my problem was a logical one.  I was setting the server hops to zero and the local hops to unlimited.  This is equal to 'Only Crawl within the server of each start address'.  It seems that SharePoint was just defaulting to that radio button option instead of using the equivalent but custom option.